# Java - New mail on inbox

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm creating a simple email robot (using Gmail) 
and I'd like to know the best approach to set a trigger that parses the message every time a new e-mail hits the inbox.

Basically, my question is -- how I can set the trigger, instead of polling for new emails.

Comment: No idea what exactly you expect to hear from us right now. Maybe a bit of example code would helpo.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your application it's hard to recommend the best approach, but you might want to look at the [support for the IMAP IDLE command](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#idle--).  You can register a [MessageCountListener](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/event/MessageCountListener.html) to be called when new messages arrive.

There's a lot more you'll need to know to make this reliable, but this should get you started.